# Reusing an object in component from container

Tags: javascript, vue.js, core-ui

I have a container and a view. I am currently hosting a `<select>` in my container that lists a bunch of sites. I then want to pass the selected sites information to a view called 'Reports.vue' so that I can display other relevant data to the selected site.

Please see the below for both my files, if needed I can update with other files such as router.

DefaultContainer:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Site</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option v-for="site in sites">{{ site.name }}</option>
        </select>
     </div>
</form>
<script>
import sites from '@/_sites'
import { Header as AppHeader, SidebarToggler, Sidebar as AppSidebar, SidebarFooter, SidebarForm, SidebarHeader, SidebarMinimizer, SidebarNav, Aside as AppAside, AsideToggler, Footer as TheFooter, Breadcrumb } from '@coreui/vue'
import DefaultAside from './DefaultAside'
import DefaultHeaderDropdownAccnt from './DefaultHeaderDropdownAccnt'

export default {
  name: 'full',
  components: {
    AsideToggler,
    AppHeader,
    AppSidebar,
    AppAside,
    TheFooter,
    Breadcrumb,
    DefaultAside,
    DefaultHeaderDropdownAccnt,
    SidebarForm,
    SidebarFooter,
    SidebarToggler,
    SidebarHeader,
    SidebarNav,
    SidebarMinimizer
  },
  data () {
    return {
      nav: nav.items,
      sites: sites.items
    }
  },
  computed: {
    name () {
      return this.$route.name
    },
    list () {
      return this.$route.matched.filter((route) => route.name || route.meta.label )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Reports.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="animated fadeIn">
    <b-row>
      <b-col sm="6" lg="3">
        <b-card bg-variant="secondary" title="Selected Site Name" sub-title="Site Address">

        </b-card>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import sites from '@/_sites'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        sites: sites.items
      }
     },
    }
</script>
```

Edit: To clarify the question:

'How do I pass the the selected object in the defaultcontainer to the view so I can display the selected objects properties? For example: site.address, site.phone, site.name'

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. What is the problem?

Comment: How do I pass the the selected object in the defaultcontainer to the view so I can display the selected objects properties? For example: site.address, site.phone, site.name

Comment: i understood that when you select a site form `select` you will be directed to `report.vue` with th elected site?

Comment: please add the router file